# Next 14 Internationalization

Tags: next.js, internationalization

I am trying to add internalization and localization to my Next 14 app. My folder structure is as below:

```
Root folder
- app
-- [lang]
----- layout.js
----- page.js
----- global.css
-- public
----- logo.svg
----- fonts
-------- fonts-woff2-files
```

When I reference any file from the public folder in my app/[lang]/page.js, file it doesn't load. I am unable to reference any static files like images and fonts etc.

```
<Image
 src="/logo.svg"
 alt="Vercel Logo"
 className={styles.brandLogo}
 width={100}
 height={24}
 priority
/>
```

What is the right way to reference static files in this case

```
<Image
 src="/logo.svg"
 alt="Vercel Logo"
 className={styles.brandLogo}
 width={100}
 height={24}
 priority
/>
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0):

Put the `public` directory to the project root:

```
Root folder
├── app
│   └── [lang]
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── page.js
│       └── global.css
└── public
    ├── logo.svg
    └── fonts
        └── fonts-woff2-files
```

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called `public` in the root directory. Files inside `public` can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

Visit the [Static Assets](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets) page for more details.

Additionally - here is [i18n example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/app-directory/i18n) by Vercel that shows how to do i18n within the app directory.